# Calling a 3rd party api through a cloud function in firebase with AXIOS POST

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make an api call with Axios POST upon the first user login on a website that uses some text and requires an api key.
I did the basic initializing stuff like `const functions = require('firebase-functions')` and `var axios = require('axios')` above.

```
exports.addSummaryMessage = functi ons.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {

    const response = await axios.post(
        'https://example.com/stuff',
        {
            headers: {
                contentType: 'content/json',
                Authorization:
                    'Bearer APIKEY',
            },
            text: 'wooooww',
        }
    )

    await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({
        name: 'Firebase Bot',
        profilePicUrl: '/images/firebase-logo.png', // Firebase logo
        text: JSON.stringify(response),
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
})
```

In my functions log I get messages like >addSummaryMessage
Function execution took 231 ms. Finished with status: error

I can track the calls received from the api and it never registers or sends back an output. All of the CORS have `request, response` which I don't think I can get with functions.auth.user().onCreate()
What's going wrong here? My API works in reqbin with this raw

```
POST /stuff
Authorization: Bearer APIKEY
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 30

{
  "text":"wooooww"
    
}
```

**EDIT**: Got it working with this text in the function:

```
    var data = {}
    var url =
        'https://example.com'
    var resp
    await axios
        .post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                contentType: 'content/json',
                Authorization:
                    'Bearer API Key',
            },
        })
        .then((res) => {
            resp = res.data.stuff

            admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({
                name: 'Firebase Bot',
                profilePicUrl: '/images/firebase-logo.png', // Firebase logo
                text: resp,
                timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

**Edit 2**
My api didnt need text to run and it was confusing me about how to pass text into the post through `data` this worked for me

```
    var userText = 'wow'
    var data = {}
    data['text'] = userText
    var url = ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to be sure about the problem you encounter without more details. But you mention that the second code works.

In addition we can see that you are not correctly [managing the life cycle of your Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions): you don't return a Promise. This typically results in some erratic behavior: the Cloud Function [sometimes works and sometimes not...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58793281/3371862)

So the following should work (untested of course, since we don't know the API called via Axios):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();   // <= This is important

exports.addSummaryMessage = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {

    const response = await axios.post(
        'https://example.com/stuff',
        {
            headers: {
                contentType: 'content/json',
                Authorization:
                    'Bearer APIKEY',
            },
            text: 'wooooww',
        }
    )

    await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({
        name: 'Firebase Bot',
        profilePicUrl: '/images/firebase-logo.png', // Firebase logo
        text: JSON.stringify(response),
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })

    return null;   // <= This is important
})
```