# Firebase custom functions POST 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i'm trying to create a custom function in Firebase custom functions to invoke a POST req to 3rd API. I was able to get together the syntax from frontend but I have no idea how to do it via firebase functions.

I need to rewrite this code - any help greatly appreciated

```
axios
  .post(
    URL,
    {
      order: {
        category_id: 7, 
        status_id: 1,
        aff_source_id: 1, 
      },
      person: {
       
        name: "n-a",
        surname: "n-a",
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
      },
      extend: {
     
        amount: maxMorgageBudget,
        repayment_time: 30,
        fixation: 5,
        house_value: maxMorgageBudget * 1.1,
        mortgage_purpose_id: mortPurpose,
        income: income,
      },
      organization: 2, 
    },
    {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      auth: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      },
    }
  )
  .then(async (response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data); // => the response payload
    }
  });
```

Comment: How this is related to reactjs?

Comment: i'm using reactjs for my frontend

Comment: If the problem can be reproduced without using ReactJS (which seems likely as I see not ReactJS specific code in the question), then it's more likely someone can help if you don't mention/tag with that technology. --- On the other hand, since you ask about Cloud Functions for Firebase, you'll want to include that tag.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016452/calling-a-3rd-party-api-through-a-cloud-function-in-firebase-with-axios-post/72020126#72020126) which shows how to use axios from a Cloud Function.