# Call Flutter web app from Node js function firebase

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I am building a ticketing application that listens to Gmail mailbox, basically, every time an email is received a new document in a collection should be created that stores the mail body subject and the attachments

I don't have experience in Node js

is it possible to call a Flutter web app page example
myapp.web.app/email-scan

using scheduled cloud function every 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to call a Flutter web app page example
> myapp.web.app/email-scan?

Yes, it is totally possible. Since we use Node.js in Cloud Functions for Firebase, you can, for example, use the [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) library to issue calls to an URL.

Here is an example: [Calling a 3rd party api through a cloud function in firebase with AXIOS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016452/calling-a-3rd-party-api-through-a-cloud-function-in-firebase-with-axios-post/72020126#72020126)

Comment: I wrote a get method using Axios and it works fine.
but the Function execution took 72 ms. Finished with status code: 200
so  Dart code can't do the job in this short time

Comment: I would like to do the server job in Dart so I want to execute a Dart code that triggers from nodeJs each 5 minutes

Comment: You can extend the time out duration of your Cloud Function as explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?hl=en#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: But 72 ms means that your code is not correctly taking into account the asynchronous aspect of the operations. Can you share your entire CF code

Comment: exports.listFruitEurope2 = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {


const response = await axios.get(
        'https://vous-project-manager.web.app',
    )
   console.log(response);

return null;
});

Comment: Your code is correct. The axios call shoudl normally wait for the response from the Dart API.

Comment: the URL is Dart web app it isn't Dart API.

Comment: Ok I mean't the URL exposed by your Dart web app